# User Interface Problem on Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-console

Hello People of Google Cloud !
A new Developer on Google Cloud based in Morocco, From the begining of my using of Google Cloud Console for our IT Project.
I faced a huge problem related to **User Interface** experinece from the first time !
The majors of web pages on Google Cloud Console not showing and working well, but other users like me here in Morocco, they haven't any problem with **user interface**.
As you see in this picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A56v.jpg)
For this I want why ? and How can I resolve it?

Anyone help me on this, espeically the GoogleCloud Team support Please !

Best Regards